# Поведение NET Flags атрибута

Tags: c#, .net

Столкнулся сегодня с загадочным поведением `enum` с атрибутом `Flags`. Первый `enum` из проекта, только имя изменил. Второй из инета, для примера. Проблема в том, что первый `enum` никак не хочет складывать значения. Уже испробовал все варианты. Взял из инета проверить поведение (подумал глюк среды), так нет, второй работает нормально.

```
class Program
{
    // это наш 
    [Flags]
    enum LabelType
    {
        A = 0,
        B = 1,
        C  = 2
    }

     // это пример из инета
    [Flags]
    enum RenderType
    {
        None = 0x0,
        DataUri = 0x1,
        GZip = 0x2,
        ContentPage = 0x4,
        ViewPage = 0x8,
        HomePage = 0x10
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RenderType type = RenderType.ViewPage;
        type |= RenderType.DataUri;
        type |= RenderType.GZip;

        // type - содержит все значения

        LabelType type2 = LabelType.C;
        type2 |= LabelType.A;
        type2 |= LabelType.B;

        / type2 - содержит только В 
    }
```

Как видно `enum` фактически одинаковые. Кроме нумерации `Value`. Но это роли не играет, проверялось(оно и не должно влиять не результат).

Кто то сталкивался с подобным ?

Answer (score 5):

Логично, потому что 0 - это пустой флаг. Не случайно же он там `None` называется.

И ещё прочитай про битовые операции, потому что чую, при добавлении следующего варианта в enum, ты в ещё одну лужу сядешь.

Comment: None роли не играет. Проверялось. И сами посудите, это просто дефолтное value. такой же как и все остальные. Про операции тоже думал, но не вижу греха. Тем более все так же, как и в примере.

Comment: @Alex, ещё как играет.

Comment: @Alex сейчас в битовых операциях греха нет. Но в примере не просто так используют hex-представление. Значение флага может быть как единичным (один конкретный бит), так и составным(несколько бит). Так что легко можно добавить флаг являющийся сочетанием набора уже имеющихся флагов. В общем про битовые операции читать внимательно и пробовать руками, чтобы видеть что получается.

Comment: Спасибо. Перечитал спецификации. кроме hex можно и 10ное использовать. Все же там нужен 0.

Answer (score 1):

Нумерация в случае флагов сильно влияет на результат. HEX-представление используют для понятности, можно и десятичное представление использовать, но читаемость потеряется где-то после 10-го флага, это не говоря про комбинированные флаги.

Пересказывать лекции по битовым операциям и двоичному представлению не буду, просто напомню, что 1 байт это ровно 2 hex-цифры, каждая из которых задает состояние ровно 4 бит. В работе удобнее использовать именно такое представление, а не десятичное.

Флаги могут быть:

- единичным, определяется одним битом;
- комбинированным, определяется набором бит, длина набора зависит от базового типа enum-а;
- пустым, значение флага 0.

С точки зрения C# и .NET типы флагов не различимы, это просто числа, но для человека такое разделение понятнее.

У пустого флага никакого особого назначения нет. Просто с помощью пустого флага можно удобно проверять отсутствие флагов в одно сравнение, вместо нескольких операций или "магических чисел" в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Для флагов обычно используются значения по степеням двойки, как и показано в примере из интернета.

то есть в вашем случае лучше переписать так:

```
[Flags]
enum LabelType
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C  = 4,
}
```